# Manga about a girl being able to see through animals' eyes and control them, who solves a crime

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this long ago but just now I had remembered it and thought about it.

I remember it was about a girl who was able to see through the eyes of animals. She does figure out she can’t do it with insects, coming to the conclusion that it may be because their minds aren’t as complex. At some point, she does control a school cat and made it approach her as she pet it, to the surprise of other students because it supposedly hated humans and never wanted to approach them.

She ends up solving a crime and gets involved with a stolen puppy that involves her guy friend because he needed the cash, and when she manages to escape with him in the forest, they get chased by the bad guys. They eventually win because of her power of animal control.

The ending was her talking about how she wants to go to the beach next and that it’d be cool to control a dolphin or something.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Answer (score 3):

As [confirmed by the OP in an edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/200042/revisions), this is the manga [*Animal Sense*](https://mangarock.com/manga/mrs-serie-14634):

> Hoshino Fuzuki, a high school student, once experienced a weird accident when she was in the 3rd grade. Now, the weird accident is coming again. She can 'get in' to an animal, then can see from the eyes of that animal. Not only sight, but she can also feel other senses that belong to the animal. What is that power?